# Rendering text to html with Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html-rendering

I am trying to render a text as html using ng-bind as the [docs show](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

`<div ng-bind-html="text"></div>`

The problem is that Angular removes the style attribute and renders this:

```
"<mark style='background-color:#FF9DFF;'>APPLE</mark>."
```

to this:

```
<mark>APPLE</mark>
```

How to render as html and keep the styles?
I am using Angular version 1.2.6

Comment: just be reminded $sce is v1.2 and above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try this function when you're doing `ng-bind-html` in your controller

```
$sce.trustAsHtml('myHTML'); //$sce would be the parameter with $scope in module
```

Hope this will work

[**$NgSanitizeDocs**](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/%24sanitize)

Answer (score 2):

First of all include [angular-sanitize.js](https://github.com/angular/bower-angular-sanitize)

```
<div ng-bind-html="deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet()"></div>
```

Then in the controller, add this method

```
pk.controller("createBlog", function($scope, $sce){
   //ace needs to be injected in the controller.
   $scope.deliberatelyTrustDangerousSnippet = function() {
       return $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.htmlcontent); //html content is th binded content.
   };
})
```